# Using histogram to sort list

Tags: python

Given a histogram as a dictionary, what is the most pythonic, "batteries included" way of sorting a list which only has elements from the dictionary, by the frequencies defined in that dictionary?

The keys of the dictionary (and implicitly the values in the list) are strings, and the frequencies are stored as integers.

I am interested only in the python2 solution, but you're welcome to write a python solution as well, so others can benefit from it too (in the future).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> inList = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> inDict = {1:5, 2:2, 3:4, 4:1, 5:3}
>>> sorted(inList, key=lambda x: inDict.get(x,0))
[4, 2, 5, 3, 1]
```

This also has the benefit of sorting elements not in the dict as if it was in the dict with a value of 0, instead of just raising a KeyError

The `sorted()` function has an optional argument 'key'. This argument specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element. This comparison key is used to determine ordering between elements.

Comment: "This argument should be a function that when called returns its position in the sorted list." Not quite; it should return a value used for comparing two elements. Like if you want to sort a list of tuples by the second element, then the key function should return the second element of a given tuple.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The way I interpret what I said, they mean the same, but since I can see other ways to interpret what I said, I have updated my answer with a more correct wording.

Answer (score 0):

In generating a histogram, I would typically use `collections.Counter`, which has a built in `.most_common()` method.  You can pass a counter-like dictionary to Counter and it will work the way you imagine it would.

```
>>> test_dict = {1: 6, 2: 8, 3: 2, 4: 4, 5: 8, 6: 4, 7: 10, 8: 3, 9: 7}
>>> c = Counter(test_dict)

# returns a list of tuples with the (item, count) values.  
>>> c.most_common()
[(7, 10), (2, 8), (5, 8), (9, 7), (1, 6), (4, 4), (6, 4), (8, 3), (3, 2)]

# if you want only the counts:
>>> [count for item, count in c.most_common()]
[10, 8, 8, 7, 6, 4, 4, 3, 2]

# if you want only the objects:
>>> [item for item, count in c.most_common()]
[7, 2, 5, 9, 1, 4, 6, 8, 3]    

# if you want them in reverse order
>>> [item for item, count in c.most_common()][::-1]
[3, 8, 6, 4, 1, 9, 5, 2, 7]
```

To create a counter object of some subset of your original count from a list-based input is trivial.  You can either use a function:

```
def return_count_from_list(oldcount, my_list):
    count = Counter()
    for i in my_list:
        count[i] = oldcount[i]
    return count
```

Or, if you only want the results, you can include your list like so:

```
my_list = [1, 4, 5]
>>> [count for item, count in c.most_common() if item in my_list]
[8, 6, 4]
```

Comment: I think OP is already generating the histogram and needs help using it to sort a dictionary.

Comment: @SamMussmann I guess I wasn't clear enough, I would pass it to a counter and use the built in method.

Comment: But what if the list you want sort doesn't contain all the keys in the dictionary?

Comment: @SamMussmann the dictionary IS the histogram, what needs to be sorted is the list.

Comment: Cool list comprehension :-)

Comment: @Flavius You said that all the elements in the list were in the dictionary/histogram, but not that all the elements in the dictionary/histogram were in the list.  Although I may be parsing your question too thoroughly. :-)